# STL vector and thread-safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, vector, thread-safety

Let's say I have a vector of N elements, but up to n elements of this vector have meaningful data. One updater thread updates the nth or n+1st element (then sets n = n+1), also checks if n is too close to N and calls vector::resize(N+M) if necessary. After updating, the thread calls multiple child threads to read up to nth data and do some calculations.

It is guaranteed that child threads never change or delete data, (in fact no data is deleted what so ever) and updater calls children just after it finishes updating.

So far no problem has occured, but I want to ask whether a problem may occur during reallocating of vector to a larger memory block, if there are some child working threads left from the previous update.
Or is it safe to use vector, as it is not thread-safe, in such a multithreaded case?

EDIT:
Since only insertion takes place when the updater calls vector::resize(N+M,0), are there any possible solutions to my problem? Due to the great performance of STL vector I am not willing to replace it with a lockable vector or in this case are there any performant,known and lock-free vectors?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I want to ask whether a problem may occur during reallocating of vector to a larger memory block, if there are some child working threads left from the previous update.

Yes, this would be very bad.

If you are using a container from multiple threads and at least one thread may perform some action that may modify the state of the container, access to the container must be synchronized.

In the case of `std::vector`, anything that changes its size (notably, insertions and erasures) change its state, even if a reallocation is not required (any insertion or erasure requires `std::vector`'s internal size bookkeeping data to be updated).

---

One solution to your problem would be to have the producer dynamically allocate the `std::vector` and use a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T> >` to own it and give this `std::shared_ptr` to each of the consumers.

When the producer needs to add more data, it can dynamically allocate a new `std::vector` with a new, larger size and copies of the elements from the old `std::vector`.  Then, when you spin off new consumers or update consumers with the new data, you simply need to give them a `std::shared_ptr` to the new `std::vector`.

Comment: @James McNellis: Yes. That's a good advice. I can do the reallocation myself. Actually vectors are wrapped within a class which holds a pointer to vector. It is not shared_ptr but I can easily construct a new larger vector, copy elements from the old one, delete it. So what is the fastest way to copy a large memory block. CopyMemory()?

Comment: Wouldn't a simpler solution be to use `std::deque` instead of a vector? That avoids the reallocations entirely, while still offering performance nearly on par with vector.

Comment: @jalf:  I don't think it's safe to use a `std::deque` because reallocations aren't the only concern.  There's no guarantee that `std::deque::operator[]` doesn't check the size or any of the other bookkeeping internal to the `deque`, so there's a potential for a race condition where a consumer calls `operator[]`, which reads the internal state while the producer is adding data, which modifies the internal state.

Comment: Actually, if `std::deque` is implemented as an array of arrays, this is certainly a problem since the array that holds the pointers to the data arrays will need to be occasionally reallocated.

Comment: @James: I don't think this would allowed, `std::deque` is forbidden to shuffle data around on `push` and `pop` operations at either end.

Comment: @Matthieu:  It's not allowed to move the data arrays.  It has to be able to move the array that holds pointers to the data arrays.  (If we consider a `std::deque` to be implemented as a `vector<unique_ptr<array<T, N>>>`, the outer `vector` is allowed to move itself around, but the pointed-to `array` objects cannot move.)

Comment: Well, there's no *guarantee* of anything as soon as threads are involved. Ultimately, it's all UB. But you're right, in practice that could be a problem, depending on how `deque` is implemented in the OP's implementation.

Comment: @jalf: what do you mean "UB"?

Comment: #User:  Undefined Behavior.  Or, "if you do this, your program is incorrect and there are no guarantees as to its behavior."

Answer (score 1):

Is how your workers decide to work on data thread safe? Is there any signaling between workers done and the producer?  If not then there is definitely an issue where the producer could cause the vector to move while it is still being worked on. Though this could trivially be fixed by moving to a `std::deque` instead.(note that `std::deque` invalidates iterators on `push_back` but references to elements are not affected).

Comment: @stonemetal: There is no signalling between workers and the producer. How am I going to use deque?

Comment: @stonemetal: I do not insert data with push_back(). I resize it then call `vec[n] = X;` Does this matter?

Comment: It depends on how you are handing out jobs to workers.  You say you only ever append to the end, so you could very well just use push_back or resize as necessary then hand out work to workers by index which never changes since you don't push or pop front or erase, you could also distribute work by a block of pointers since elements are guarantied to not move, though they are not guarantied to be contiguous so you would need a pointer to each element a worker needed rather than an array style start and length setup. Iterators are invalidated on resize so they wouldn't be an option.

Comment: It's still not safe.  There's no guarantee that the `operator[]` overload won't check the size of the container or other internal state bookkeeping of the container, so there's a potential race condition.

Comment: There is a race condition on weather or not the workers see the length of the deque as n or n+x but since he is explicitly limiting access to < n then there is no race condition that will produce a fault.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

I've made my own GrowVector. It works for me and it is really fast.

Link: [QList, QVector or std::vector multi-threaded usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597101/qlist-qvector-or-stdvector-multi-threaded-usage)