# QList, QVector or std::vector multi-threaded usage

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety, containers

I would like two threads work like this:

1. First thread will append values to vector
2. Second thread will have read-only access to elements by index

I can make mutex and make deep copy before second thread start reading.... But this way is really slow... How is it possible to make this without mutex? Here: [STL vector and thread-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346742/stl-vector-and-thread-safety)
I read that it is possible to use std::deque, but it fails like std::vector ...

Where I can find append-only container, which don't realloc data?

---

I have solved my problem by creating own container GrowVector with operations: adding elements to back, getting size, accessing element by index. It works for 2Billion elements for default, but it can be changed by constructor parameter.

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class GrowVector
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T> > m_data;
    size_t m_size;

public:
    GrowVector(int chunks = 32768)
        : m_data()
        , m_size(0)
    {
        m_data.reserve(chunks);
        m_data.push_back(std::vector<T>());
        m_data.back().reserve(1 << 16);
    }

    void add(const T & value)
    {
        if (m_data.back().size() == m_data.back().capacity())
        {
            m_data.push_back(std::vector<T>());
            m_data.back().reserve(1 << 16);
        }

        m_data.back().push_back(value);
        m_size++;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    T & operator [] (int i)
    {
        return m_data[i >> 16][i & 0xffff]; 
    }

    const T & operator [] (int i) const
    {
        return m_data[i >> 16][i & 0xffff];    
    }
};
```

Is my solution safe?

Comment: If you use a Standard Library container from multiple threads and at least one thread is modifying the container, you must synchronize access to the container.  This is the case for all Standard Library containers, not just for `vector`.

Comment: The only way to not reallocate memory is if you already know the maximum amount of entries you will have in the vector, and then use `reserve`. Or `std::array` if you know the size already at compile-time. Maybe you want a `std::list` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not thread-safe without a locking mechanism.

You can use [tbb::concurrent_vector](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/wiki/index.php?title=Concurrent_Vector) or [Concurrency::concurrent_vector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355343.aspx) for multiple insertion and access simultaneously. No extra locking required. It is unsafe to erase elements from those vectors, but you are ok with it I guess.

Comment: Thank you. TBB's concurrent_vector look like what i need.

Answer (score 3):

`QList` and `QVector` are re-entrant, so as long as you never the read the last entry whilst thread one is active (so you don't get a value mid-write), and always use `at()` in the second thread (so no deep copy occurs, this avoids issues with the growth reallocation) you should be OK.

Otherwise you need synchronisation.

Answer (score 2):

STL containers does not provide thread safe by default. For concurrent operations on data structures, it is best to provide your own synchronized access to meet thread safe operations.