# writing thread safe in a vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, vector, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [STL vector and thread-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346742/stl-vector-and-thread-safety)

If I have this piece of code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> a;
std::vector<double> b;

// init a,b....

std::vector<double> c;
parallel_for_each (a.begin(); a.end; [&c, &b] (std::vector<double>& aux) {
   c.push_back(foo(b, aux));
});
```

It is thread safe to add elements like that in the vector ?

Comment: Use mutex for thread safety ..

Comment: @WhozCraig: I can't agree that it's an exact duplicate -- that question has tighter conditions so more careful analysis is needed to determine thread safety (or lack thereof). This one is much simpler, leading to a simpler, more clear-cut answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `std::vector` is not thread-safe. You have to provide synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

Where is that parallel_for_each coming from? If it's from Microsoft's concurrency library, just use concurrent_vector.